# Почему возникает ошибка «Call to a member function saveAs() on null»?

Tags: yii2

вот контролер

```
public function actionCreate(){
  $module=$this->module;
  $model= new MenuGet();
  $uploadModel=new UploadImage();
  if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax) {
       $request=Yii::$app->request;
        if($request->isPost){
        $fileName = 'file';
        if (isset($_FILES[$fileName])) {
        $file = \yii\web\UploadedFile::getInstanceByName($fileName);
       $uplImg=$uploadModel->upload($file ,$module);
        if ($uplImg) {
        return $this->render('create', [
              'model' => $model,
               'module' => $module,
                'uploadModel' => $uploadModel
        ]);
         }
     }
}
```

вот `UploadImage`

```
class UploadImage extends Model
{
    public $file;
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['file'], 'file','skipOnEmpty' => true, 'extensions' => 'png, jpg, jpeg, gif'],
        ];
    }
    public function upload($fileName,$module){

        $basePath=date('Y').'/'.date('m');
        $uploadPath =$module->imageDownloadPath.''.$basePath;
        if (file_exists($uploadPath)) {
        } else {
            mkdir($uploadPath, 0777, true);
        }
        $file = \yii\web\UploadedFile::getInstanceByName($fileName);
        $filenames=$this->traranslitImg($file->name);
        if ($this->validate()) {
            if(file_exists($uploadPath)) {
            } else {
                mkdir($uploadPath, 0777, true);
            }
            if ($this->file->saveAs($uploadPath . '/' . $filenames)){
                $this->imagerisize($uploadPath, $filenames,$module);
                return true;
            };
        } else {
            return var_dump($this->getErrors());
        }
    }
```

картинка грузится через `dropzone` но приходит ответ

> Exception 'Error' with message 'Call to a member function saveAs() on
>   null'
>
> ```
> in /var/www/magaz.lc/vendor/sirgalas/yii2-wordperss-menu/models/UploadImage.php:41
> ```

Comment: Очевидно, вы нигде не инициализируете $this->file

Comment: @etki `public $file;` , а это разве не инициализация ?

Comment: @etki  все понял я забыл значение присвоить $this->file вы это же имели в виду ?

Comment: @Sergalas да, он это имел в виду. ....`public $file;` — это объявление..... `$file = БЛА БЛА БЛА;` — инициализация, т.е. присвоение некого значения

Comment: @АлексейШиманский спасибо я так и сделал